# VueJS plugin rendering problems. Vue Formulate

Tags: forms, vue.js, plugins, vue-formulate

So i am not profeccional in vueJs that`s why if you need some more additional information just write in coments i will try to provide it...
This is the way that i intalling this plugin

```
import VueFormulate from '@braid/vue-formulate';
Vue.use(VueFormulate);
```

and in my template where i want to use this plugin

```
<FormulateInput
  type="email"
  name="email"
  label="Enter your email address"
  help="We’ll send you an email when your ice cream is ready"
  validation="required|email"
/>
```

but on browser page there is nothing and what i see in rendered page tree

```
<formulateinput 
  type="email" 
  name="email" 
  label="Enter your email address" 
  help="We’ll send you an email when your ice cream is ready" 
  validation="required|email">
</formulateinput>
```

So as i can see it is not rendered.

A little interting thing. When component where i whant to use plugin mounted then output in console plugin object, and it is exits

```
mounted() {  
   console.log(VueFormulate); 
}
```

screen from console
[image: screen from console]

can you please help me to find what i miss? :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was in template tags.

And VueFormulate component in my template **must be lower-cased, hyphen separated and with a closing tag**

```
<formulate-input
  type="email"
  name="email"
  label="Enter your email address"
  help="We’ll send you an email when your ice cream is ready"
  validation="required|email"
></formulate-input>
```

instead of

```
<FormulateInput
  type="email"
  name="email"
  label="Enter your email address"
  help="We’ll send you an email when your ice cream is ready"
  validation="required|email"
/>
```

More information about syntax style:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended

[image]

Comment: Having the same problem, my error were closing tags. Docs say nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

try this working code:

App.js

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <FormulateInput
  type="email"
  name="email"
  label="Enter your email address"
  help="We’ll send you an email when your ice cream is ready"
  validation="required|email"
/></div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import VueFormulate from '@braid/vue-formulate';
Vue.use(VueFormulate);

export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

and Main.js must be like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

It actually render component but without style! if you want to use component style, write :

```
@import '../node_modules/@braid/vue-formulate/themes/snow/snow.scss';
```

in your scss style file or import https://github.com/wearebraid/vue-formulate/blob/master/dist/snow.min.css in your project!

Comment: thanks you for your answer, it helps me and set on the right track